# toggling bold on selected text in an editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im writing a page editor for my schools website, all is going well but ive hit an issue with removing font styles from the selected text. I can select the text and get jquery to apply a span tag to it with a css class associated, my problem comes when i want to remove that class from the selected text. Heres what i have so far...

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true">
Editable Content
</div>
```

I have an event listener that picks up the bold button press and triggers the function below...

```
function makeBold() {
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
alert(range.anchorNode.parentNode.nodevalue);
var newNode = document.createElement('span');
newNode.className = "bold-text";
range.surroundContents(newNode);
}
```

This function works great to apply the style, but i cant figure out how i would then remove it with a toggle. Im struggling to understand how to use the range selection to remove the parent tags. i was trying to use the `.closest()` selector but keep getting object or undefined errors? Can anyone tell me if im on the right track?

Thanks

Dave

**Edit :**

im not using a typical selector like #myid or .classname i need to apply the style to the text that is selected by the user, hence why im wrapping it with span tags with the function above. idealy i need to find a way of finding the closest parent node with the .bold-text class applied to it and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'removeClass' method of jQuery to remove the class which you have given to the text which is going to be formatted. On every toggle, `addClass` and `removeClass`

http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Do it something like this

on click one - `$('#id').addClass('class_of_text');`

on click two - `$('.class_of_text').removeClass('.class_of_text);`

on click three - `$('#id').addClass('class_of_text');`

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would i use the range selection as a selector? Ive tried $(range) but it doesnt work?

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you said. But see the edit if that helps out. If not, please clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: im not using a typical selector like #myid or .classname i need to apply the style to the text that is selected by the user, hence why im wrapping it with span tags with the function above. idealy i need to find a way of finding the closest parent node with the .bold-text class applied to it and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeattribute of javascript to remove the class attribute from that element.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i dont think it will work with the range selection. I need a way to find the parent span tag that has the class .bold-text applied to it?

Comment: Yeah, You are write, how can we select the parent of the selected text.? I'll inform you if I found something useful. thanks.